# Keras: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_26: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a text classification problem and I'm using a LSTM layer to get the context vectors, using Keras.

I used the `tokenizer` and padded the sequences so my `X_train` has the shape `(21226, 1500)` where 1500 is the max sequence length.

How do I directly pass this sequence to an LSTM with 64 units? I tried doing it directly but there appears to be an issue with the dimensions.

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_26: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Here is the code, in Keras:

```
input = Input(shape=(1500,))
lstm1 = LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)
out = lstm1(input)
```

Edit:

Here is the updated code:

```
def getm():
    inp = Input(shape=(1500,1))
    lstm1 = LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)
    out = lstm1(inp)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=custom_loss, metrics=[custom_loss])
    return model
```

Now, X_train's shape is (21226, 1500), after reshaping with np.expand_dims, it is (21226, 1500, 1).

I read the Keras docs and in X_train's shape, the first attribute should be the batch size, which should be None as Keras' predict and fit functions take care of that.

EDIT2:

Here's the complete code:

```
def getm():
    inp = Input(shape=(1500,1))
    lstm1 = LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)
    out = lstm1(inp)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=custom_loss, metrics=[custom_loss])
    return model

model = getm()

X_train.shape = (21226, 500)
```

I reshape this using

```
my_data = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape + (1,))
```

Now,

```
my_data.shape = (21226, 1500, 1)
```

I'm trying to predict the output for one data point:

```
 model.predict(my_data[0])
```

And this error is thrown:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_25 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1500, 1)
```

EDIT3:

This is the model summary

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_25 (InputLayer)        (None, 1500, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_16 (LSTM)               (None, 64)                16896     
=================================================================
Total params: 16,896
Trainable params: 16,896
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LSTM` layer expects a 3D input array of shape `(batch_size, num_timesteps or sequence_length, num_features)` (that's why you are getting `expected ndim=3, found ndim=2` error). So if you would like to feed your tokenized and word-indexed sentences directly to a LSTM layer you need to reshape it such that it also has a feature axis (which in this case would contain the index of the words in the dictionary):

```
# using np.reshape
my_data = my_data.reshape(my_data.shape + (1,))

# using np.expand_dims
my_data = np.expand_dims(my_data, axis=-1)
```

Comment: For me, X_train's shape is (21226, 1500). I tried using np.expand_dims and the new shape is (21226, 1500, 1).  I'm getting this error. now. "Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4".

Comment: @Reptilian Have you updated the input layer shape accordingly? i.e. it must be `Input(shape=(1500,1))`.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the model compilation but when I attempt to fit or predict, it throws this error.  `Error when checking input: expected input_25 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (21226, 1500)`

Comment: @Reptilian Make sure `X_train.shape` is `(?,?,1)`. By the way, where have you used 200? In input shape?

Comment: Added the updated code. I'm trying to predict the output for one training instance and it throws this error. `Error when checking input: expected input_25 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (21226, 1500)`

Comment: @Reptilian Very strange! You mentioned that `X_train.shape` is `(21226, 1500,1)` which means it is 3D array, however it complains that you are feeding it an array of shape `(21226, 1500)`. All I can say is to make sure all the input arrays (training, validation, test) are 3D arrays.

Comment: The docs state that `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`should be the input shape. My training dataset has 21k datapoints with each point being an encoded vector (vocabulary) of length 1500. Reshaping it produces X_train with shape (21226, 1500,1) which again throws the same error.

Comment: @Reptilian Could you edit your post and add the complete code containing the reshaping process as well `fit` method call?

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out now. It works. The shapes are confusing. Thanks a lot!